# Data changed after saving with soundfile and reading with librosa

Tags: python, librosa, soundfile

I am processing  an audio file with librosa as:

```
import librosa
import soundfile as sf

y,sr = librosa.cora.load('test.wav', sr=22050)
y_processed = some_processing(y)
sf.write('test_processed.wav', y_processed , sr)
y_read = librosa.cora.load('test_processed.wav', sr=22050)
```

Now the issue is that y_processed and y_read do not match. My understanding is that this comes from some encoding done by soundfile library. Why is this happening and how can I get from y_processed to y_read without saving?

Comment: Why are you saving at all?

Comment: The processing-saving and reading are in different parts of the project but using the same data. Now I needed to merge these parts into one tool but I have the model already trained using this saved-read data, so now I am trying to figure how to avoid saving and reading to get the correct data

Comment: what version of librosa and soundfile are you using?
the new librosa version not using core.load, see: https://librosa.org/doc/0.9.1/generated/librosa.load.html

Comment: also, can you post an example of the different values (maybe first 10 elements of each)
are you sure the original sr is 22050 ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/comet-ml/applyingmachinelearningtoaudioanalysis-utm-source-kdnuggets11-19-e160b069e88), librosa.load(), along with other things, normalizes the bit depth between -1 and 1.

I experienced the same problem as you did, where the min and max values of the "loaded" signal were much closer to each other.

Since I don't exactly how your data differs from each other, this may not help you, but this has helped me.

```
y_processed_buf = librosa.util.buf_to_float(y_processed)
```

This seems to be the culprit, which would normalizes your values ([source code](https://librosa.org/doc/main/_modules/librosa/util/utils.html#buf_to_float)). It is also called during librosa.load(), which is how I stumbled over it.